# Viewing Wrapper/Container Classes from a Scriptable Object inside of the Unity Inspector

Tags: unity, scriptable-object, bolt-visual-scripting

I'm making a word game to teach kids how to read and promote literacy. As part of that, I made a Scriptable Object that's basically a bunch of nested Lists, until it reaches the bottom node:

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
 
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New WordPronunciationData", menuName = "Word Pronunciation Data", order = 51)]
 
public class WordPronunciationData : ScriptableObject
{
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
        public class NeemUnitContainer {
        public List<NeemUnit> NeemUnitContainers;
}
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
        public class Syllable {
        public List<NeemUnitContainer> Syllables;
}
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
    public class NeemUnit {
        [SerializeField]
        public List<FlexNeem> individualNeem;
         
    }
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
    public class FlexNeem{
        [SerializeField]
        public NeemData superNeem;
     
        [SerializeField]
        public FeemData Feem;
 
    }
 
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
    public class CompleteWordList{        
            public List<Syllable> completeWord;
    }
    public List<CompleteWordList> allWords;
 
}
```

It's working great, and I can view and edit data in the Scriptable Objects perfectly.

[image]

But when I try to pull data from the Scriptable Object into Scene variables... I can't see them in the graph's Inspector.

[image]

However for the bottom node in my Scriptable Object... I defined the class as calling 2 other Scriptable Objects:

```
    [System.Serializable]
 
    [IncludeInSettings(true)]
    public class FlexNeem{
        [SerializeField]
        public NeemData superNeem;
     
        [SerializeField]
        public FeemData Feem;
 
    }
```

And when I create a variable and put data from these into them, they do show up very nicely in the Inspector.

[image]

But somehow when I make a container/wrapper class around this to make a List, and then put that data into a variable... it no longer shows up in a Inspector containing that variable.

[image]

This is making debugging much harder.  I can only see how many items are in the list, not what the item is.

Is this just the nature of creating so many wrapper/container classes with lists?  Is there a way I could view the wrapper/container classes in the Inspector, rather than just seeing "No Inspector For..."?

If anyone has tips or advice, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you!!

Comment: I noticed that you declare many inner classes, maybe you should create a `.cs` file for each class. In many cases custom structures require instanceID to be displayed in the inspector, so they require separate files.

Comment: I did consider maybe separate Scriptable Objects for the classes... but then wouldn't I have to make a bunch of separate component Scriptable Object Assets and drag them into my Scriptable Object for Word Pronunciation?  I'm hoping I only have to do that for the SuperNeem and Feem assets...